# Client Object Model to SharePoint Links List

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

I want to get URLs from SharePoint Links list using client object model javascript, can someone help me, I tried the following script but when I am alerting its result it shows me the URL value as [object Object] but not the actual URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var siteUrl = '/';

function retrieveListItems() {
alert("hello");
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Links');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    //camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nURL: ' + oListItem.get_item('URL');
            //'\nFieldName: ' + oListItem.get_item('Notes');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}</script><input id="button1" onclick="retrieveListItems()" type="button" value="GetItems"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.get_url()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556308%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

This should work:

```
var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nURL: ' + oListItem.get_item('URL').get_url();
```

Comment: Np, same goes for other types too, like lookup. You should take a look in the SP.Namespace overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557057(v=office.14).aspx